# Angular 2 and RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to build an example realtime app with Angular 2.0.0RC5 and RxJS 5.0.0-beta.6. Although I it is all working with this code:

```
import {IntervalObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';
    ...
return IntervalObservable.create(1000)
                .flatMap(() => this.http.get('filename.json'))
                .map(this.extractDataCallBack)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

Is this the correct way? The current RxJS api docs seem to specify different methods. Is there a way to upgrade to the latest version of RxJS without breaking everything?

What happened to the `Observable.interval()` function? I have seen several examples using this.

Anything you can offer to shine a bit of light onto this would be great.

Many thanks

JT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.interval` is just a shortcut to `IntervalObservable.create`:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/interval.ts

Comment: if I set the polling interval, how do I get the polling to start immediately? Rather than after the specified polling interval.

Comment: Try `Observable.concat(Observable.of(null), Observable.interval(1000)).flatMap...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, so this worked.

```
import { Observable }   from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';
import {IntervalObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';

...

private serverGetRequestContinuous(requestInterval: number, jsonFileName: String): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.concat(Observable.of(null), IntervalObservable.create(10000))
            .flatMap(() => this.http.get('filename.json'))
            .map(this.extractDataCallBack)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

By concatenatinge these two Observables there is no delay for the first request. If IntervalObservable.create(requestInterval) was called alone, the polling would start only after the specified requestInterval. This first Observable causes a single request right now and thus no delay in displaying data in the UI. The second Observable polls every 10 seconds.